# Find and Replace using Regex

Tags: regex, string, text, replace, editor

I have a text file in which I have certain numbers of the type-

```
a.bcdef0000000000000e+05
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f can take any values in 0-9. I want to find all of them and replace their value with abcdef i.e. 6 digits without the decimal point. How can I do it using regex in Linux or an editor like Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1):

cheack for the regex ([\d]).([\d]{5})0*e+\d* or make changes in grouping of your regex and replace it with $1$2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([0-9]\.[0-9]{5}[0]{13}[e]\+05)
```

Demo:

http://regex101.com/r/jM9tQ6

Comment: Thanks for this great resource. But how do I replace them with abcdef?

Comment: An improved one for my case would be ([0-9]\.[0-9]{5}[0]{13}[e]\+05*). Now that the find part is done, any way for the replace?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\{5\}\)0000000000000e+05/\1\2/g' <filename>
```

Explanation of the individual parts of the command:

- `sed`: program name
- `-i`: use in-place substitution (make sure to create a backup of your files before you start!)
- `'s/.../.../g'`: sed command: will search for the pattern between the first two slashes and substitute (hence the `s`) with the replacement between the second two slashes. `g` makes sed search/replace all matches, not just the first
- `\([0-9]\.[0-9]\{5\}\)0000000000000e+05`: search pattern:

  - `\(...\)`: grouping: allows us to reference the pattern in the substitution using `\1`, `\2` etc.
  - `[0-9]`: matches any single digit
  - `\.`: matches a single dot (just `.` would match any non-newline character)
  - `\{n\}`: match the preceding pattern `n` times (in our case: match 5 consecutive digits)
  - `0000000000000e+05`: matches the literal characters
- `\1\2` replace pattern: `\0`, `\1`, `\2` etc. put partial matches of the pattern into the substitution string. `\0` matches the entire pattern, and `\1` matches the first subpattern, `\2` the second subpattern etc. Subpatterns are marked using escaped parens, like so: `\(...\)`

Comment: I am getting sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'

Comment: ok, I corrected the ending quote but it did not remove the decimal point. Can you edit with the correct answer?

Comment: Done. You must place the closing quote after the `.../g`, not after the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text solution. Go to Find->Replace... (Ctrl+H), change to Regular expression search (Alt+R), then:

"Find What:" `([\d]).([\d]{5})0*e\+\d*`

"Replace With:" `$1$2$3$4$5$6`